# Implement two different color for Highlighted and selected state for custom cell of UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want to implement touch up and touch down like functionality for my TableView Cell. 
My need is giving different background color to the cell.
Give different background when we touch down the cell and different color when we touch up.

I try it with following way :

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didHighlightRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
     [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];   
 }

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]]; 
}
```

but the issue is `didHighlightRowAtIndexPath` is only available for `iOS 6.0` not below that.

Is there another way to implement it.

Comment: you can set backgroung color of your cell and change color on didselectrowatindexpath

Comment: can you please elaborate

Comment: ok, I am providing some code snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` write below code:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CustomCellIdentifier = @"yourcell";

    SettingsCell *cell = (SettingsCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CustomCellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {

        NSArray *nib = nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"yourcell" owner:self options:nil];


        for(id oneObject in nib) {
            if([oneObject isKindOfClass:[yourCell class]]) {
                cell = (yourCell *)oneObject;
            }
        }

        //to change background color of selected cell
        UIView *backgroundView          = [[UIView alloc] init];
        backgroundView.backgroundColor  = [UIColor blueColor];
        cell.selectedBackgroundView     = backgroundView;

    }

    return cell;
}
```

And on didselectRow at indexPath, change to another color

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    
    [tableView reloadData];
    UITableViewCell *cell=(UITableViewCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you can have two images for selected and unselected rows.

```
cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unselected.png"] ];

cell.selectedBackgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage  imageNamed:@"selected.png"] ];
```

You will be adding this in cellForRowAtIndexPath method. You can take state from didSelect right?? Trust me i have tried almost 10 different ways to do this and only this solution worked fine in all cases perfectly.

Comment: but how can i get the states here?

Comment: i get the select state from didselect not highlighted state .

Comment: Yeah adding the above code in cellForRow is enuf and in didSelect you don't have to do anything.